# How to add a static header in JSQMessageView Controller

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

How i can add header just like the image below which should not scroll up with view controller.

[image]

Comment: Man I'm glad to know CSS, you'd just use `flex: 0 0 auto`. I do want to learn swift though. You might want to check out Kapeli Dash for quick documentation lookups.

Answer (score 1):

**To add static header view, use following function (Swift 4):**

**Note:** I have tried to put this kind of header view directly using storyboard. But, it wont worked. So, finally I achieved it by adding programatically.

```
func addHeaderView() {
        let selectableView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 60))
        selectableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 120.0/255.0, blue: 222.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"ArrowBack"), for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = 1
        selectableView.addSubview(btn)

        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: btn.frame.size.width+5, y: 5, width: selectableView.frame.size.width-60, height: 18))
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel.text = "Winter event 2017"
        selectableView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        let subTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: btn.frame.size.width+5, y: 30, width: 100, height: 16))
        subTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        subTitleLabel.text = "135 members"
        selectableView.addSubview(subTitleLabel)

        let btnOptions: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: selectableView.frame.size.width-60, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        btnOptions.setImage(UIImage(named:"Settings"), for: .normal)
        btnOptions.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnOptions.tag = 2
        selectableView.addSubview(btnOptions)

        view.addSubview(selectableView)
    }

    //then make a action method :

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
        if btnsendtag.tag == 1 {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            askForSettings()
        }
    }
```

Also put this line of code in viewDidLoad()

```
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: hii bro i need help in JSQMessageView Controller i have hidden a navigation bar in ChatViewController and dragged a UIView of height = 60 and make a custom navigation bar but it is hidden i m not able to see that @Sagar Sukode

Comment: @DilipTiwari: As I have already mention NOTE in my answer. For me also, wont work using storyboard/xib. So better to write code to add header view.

Comment: yes after writing ur code it now shows static header view, i want to set label at centre of that uiview how will i do @Sagar Sukode

Comment: @DilipTiwari: Check this code for centering the label:
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: btn.frame.size.width+5, y: yAxisForButton+10, width: ScreenWidth-100, height: 18))
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center